# How do I send a privatemsg to all users that have flagged a node using Rules?

Tags: rules, flags

I am using the [Privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module, [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

I wonder if using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) I could send a private message to all the people who have flagged a specific node when a new comment is posted.

Thus, the flag would act like a subscription for new comments notification.

Comment: Is this for D7 ?

Comment: interesting profile picture ... if I was to update mine in a similar way, I would need 2 such pictures, no? Btw, just fixed some outstanding issue that was still waiting recovery ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new rule triggered on After saving a new comment`.
2. No conditions necessary; set them up only if you require something specific.
3. Actions:

   - Fetch users who have flagged a node
   - Loop through those users (argument will be populated automatically)
   - Under that loop create a new action "Send a message". This will require you to have "Privatemsg Rules Integrations" module enabled.

Comment: ok so I did #1 and #2 for #3 I don't see a "Fetch users who have a flagged a node" see pic --> http://s28.postimg.org/albqryl7x/flag1.jpg I tried using fetch users who flagged a content and got this screen http://s7.postimg.org/hkll45g4q/flag2.jpg Then I added a loop http://s28.postimg.org/68rfy4xkc/flag3.jpg Then under loop I added an action to send message but I get this screen http://postimg.org/image/vhhly87jh/ but I don

Comment: ...but I don't know what to put for recipient, it wont let me just use users:

Comment: Just use the `list-item` - that is the current item in the loop.

Comment: ah thanks list-item looks like it should be used there, but I'm still not getting any messages, something must be wrong elsewhere humm

Comment: I did this on a clean installation before posting so it should be working without any issues; make sure the flags are enabled for the content type of your node and that you are subscribed to it. Try doing it on a clean install as well.

Comment: humm interesting in clean install I get the "fetch users who have flagged a node" option and the "flagged a content" is gone. Seems like another module is interfering or something, I got it working on the clean install, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Next step is to clone the site and start disabling the modules one by one and checking if it's working. That way you can narrow the issue down to a specific module. It doesn't need to be a bug, it can be a misconfiguration or overlapping functionality.